# Calling UIAlertViewDelegate method from different ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, uialertview

Several ViewControllers in my application have to show the same UIAlertView and perform – alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method in the same manner. I don't want to write same code in several files so i need to have a kind of global UIAlertView with one alertView: clickedButtonAtIndex: method available for all my ViewControllers. I've created a method which calls the UIAlertView in my AppDelegate.m file and overridden alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: in the same place, but unfortunately alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: doesn't get called from the different file. Do you have any ideas? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you subclass `UIViewController` to have all the functionality you require for the `UIAlertView`, and then have your `AppDelegate` cal that method on the current subclassed `UIViewController` on the navigation stack. Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 2):

when you create the UIAlertView in your other view controllers, make sure the delegate is set to your AppDelegate (or whererever the `clickedButtonAtIndex:` method is declared)